# Make selected custom shipping method shows custom input textarea at onepage checkout

Tags: magento2, layout, onepage-checkout, additional-information, custom-shipping-method

I successfully added custom shipping method like this:

**app/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <lime>
                <active>1</active>
                <allowed_methods>delivery</allowed_methods>
                <methods>delivery</methods>
                <type>NAMESPACE</type>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
                <model>Namespace\Module\Model\Carrier</model>
                <name>Namespace_Module custom Shipping</name>
                <title>Namespace_Module custom Shipping</title>
                <handling_type>F</handling_type>
            </lime>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

**app/code/Namespace/Module/Model/Carrier.php**

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    } 
    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create(); 
    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create(); 
    $method->setCarrier('HILO');
    $method->setCarrierTitle('HILO'); 
    $method->setMethod('Fast');
    $method->setMethodTitle('Fast'); 
    $amount = $this->getConfigData('price'); 
    $method->setPrice($amount);
    $method->setCost($amount); 
    $result->append($method);
    return $result;
}
```

It shows up at checkout page, but I want to show custom text area input data when the user choose my custom shipping method, and I can save the custom input text area data.

here's what I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: hi, how did you add this field?can you please help me to get a code?

Answer (score 1):

In order to show a custom input field after selecting your custom shipping method, you have to add a js block subscribing to select method event:

Add a **custom phtml** to layout **checkout_index_index.xml**

Then add the next block to your phtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    ], function (jQuery, quote) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            quote.shippingMethod.subscribe(function (value) {
                if (quote.shippingMethod() && quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code == 'your_custom_shipping_method_code') {
                    var customBlock = "<div class ='custom-information'><input type="text" id="your_custom_id"></div>";
                    if((!$('.custom-information').length > 0)) {
                        $('#checkout-shipping-method-load').append(customBlock);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

With the above code, you will add the input you want below your custom shipping method.

After that, you should have to create a plugin to save your custom value.

> Check: **Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestShippingInformationManagement**

I hope it helps you.
Regards,
Pablo

Comment: can you please explain this little more

Comment: While this may work in some fashion, this isn't best practice and definitely something to try and get away from doing. Specifically, the use of jQuery as a hammer to inject content into the page like this.

Answer (score 1):

**view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="carrier_custom" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/shipping/carrier_custom</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```

**view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping/carrier_custom.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, ko, Component, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/checkout/shipping/carrier_custom'
        },

        initObservable: function () {

            this.selectedMethod = ko.computed(function() {
                var method = quote.shippingMethod();
                var selectedMethod = method != null ? method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code : null;
                return selectedMethod;
            }, this);

            return this;
        },
    });
});
```

**view/frontend/web/template/checkout/shipping/carrier_custom.html**

```
<div id="my-carrier-custom-block-wrapper" data-bind="visible: selectedMethod() == 'mycarrier_mymethod'">
    <p data-bind="i18n: 'This is custom block shown only when selected specific method'"></p>
</div>
```